# Swift 3: How to get language code from a country code?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, swift3

I want to get the main language of a country. For example: "US" -> "en" or "VN" -> "vi" In Swift 3, are there any ways to do this?

Comment: I'm skeptical this is possible. What's the definition of "main"? Canada officially has 2 equally official languages, English and French. I doubt any standardizing body like ISO would recognize English as more "main" than French.

Answer (score 6):

The system has a list of common locales that include both a language and region.  You can use this to get common languages for a region.  There is no concept of a main language in a `Locale`.

```
func commonLanguages(for region:String) -> [String] {
    return Locale.availableIdentifiers
        .map { Locale(identifier:$0) }
        .filter { $0.regionCode == region }
        .map { $0.languageCode ?? "??" }
}
```

Comment: Like @Alexander said in a comment to the OP, what happens with Canada? Since an array is the return, will it pass back two languages?

Comment: this will return an array and the array first language is not the common language of that country for example for Japan it will return ["en","jp"] so how can I get only one common Language in that country ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a predefined language code list to identify the language code

```
let array: [String] = [
"af-ZA",
"am-ET",
"ar-AE",
"ar-BH",
"ar-DZ",
"ar-EG",
"ar-IQ",
"ar-JO",
"ar-KW",
"ar-LB",
"ar-LY",
"ar-MA",
"arn-CL",
"ar-OM",
"ar-QA",
"ar-SA",
"ar-SY",
"ar-TN",
"ar-YE",
"as-IN",
"az-Cyrl-AZ",
"az-Latn-AZ",
"ba-RU",
"be-BY",
"bg-BG",
"bn-BD",
"bn-IN",
"bo-CN",
"br-FR",
"bs-Cyrl-BA",
"bs-Latn-BA",
"ca-ES",
"co-FR",
"cs-CZ",
"cy-GB",
"da-DK",
"de-AT",
"de-CH",
"de-DE",
"de-LI",
"de-LU",
"dsb-DE",
"dv-MV",
"el-GR",
"en-029",
"en-AU",
"en-BZ",
"en-CA",
"en-GB",
"en-IE",
"en-IN",
"en-JM",
"en-MY",
"en-NZ",
"en-PH",
"en-SG",
"en-TT",
"en-US",
"en-ZA",
"en-ZW",
"es-AR",
"es-BO",
"es-CL",
"es-CO",
"es-CR",
"es-DO",
"es-EC",
"es-ES",
"es-GT",
"es-HN",
"es-MX",
"es-NI",
"es-PA",
"es-PE",
"es-PR",
"es-PY",
"es-SV",
"es-US",
"es-UY",
"es-VE",
"et-EE",
"eu-ES",
"fa-IR",
"fi-FI",
"fil-PH",
"fo-FO",
"fr-BE",
"fr-CA",
"fr-CH",
"fr-FR",
"fr-LU",
"fr-MC",
"fy-NL",
"ga-IE",
"gd-GB",
"gl-ES",
"gsw-FR",
"gu-IN",
"ha-Latn-NG",
"he-IL",
"hi-IN",
"hr-BA",
"hr-HR",
"hsb-DE",
"hu-HU",
"hy-AM",
"id-ID",
"ig-NG",
"ii-CN",
"is-IS",
"it-CH",
"it-IT",
"iu-Cans-CA",
"iu-Latn-CA",
"ja-JP",
"ka-GE",
"kk-KZ",
"kl-GL",
"km-KH",
"kn-IN",
"kok-IN",
"ko-KR",
"ky-KG",
"lb-LU",
"lo-LA",
"lt-LT",
"lv-LV",
"mi-NZ",
"mk-MK",
"ml-IN",
"mn-MN",
"mn-Mong-CN",
"moh-CA",
"mr-IN",
"ms-BN",
"ms-MY",
"mt-MT",
"nb-NO",
"ne-NP",
"nl-BE",
"nl-NL",
"nn-NO",
"nso-ZA",
"oc-FR",
"or-IN",
"pa-IN",
"pl-PL",
"prs-AF",
"ps-AF",
"pt-BR",
"pt-PT",
"qut-GT",
"quz-BO",
"quz-EC",
"quz-PE",
"rm-CH",
"ro-RO",
"ru-RU",
"rw-RW",
"sah-RU",
"sa-IN",
"se-FI",
"se-NO",
"se-SE",
"si-LK",
"sk-SK",
"sl-SI",
"sma-NO",
"sma-SE",
"smj-NO",
"smj-SE",
"smn-FI",
"sms-FI",
"sq-AL",
"sr-Cyrl-BA",
"sr-Cyrl-CS",
"sr-Cyrl-ME",
"sr-Cyrl-RS",
"sr-Latn-BA",
"sr-Latn-CS",
"sr-Latn-ME",
"sr-Latn-RS",
"sv-FI",
"sv-SE",
"sw-KE",
"syr-SY",
"ta-IN",
"te-IN",
"tg-Cyrl-TJ",
"th-TH",
"tk-TM",
"tn-ZA",
"tr-TR",
"tt-RU",
"tzm-Latn-DZ",
"ug-CN",
"uk-UA",
"ur-PK",
"uz-Cyrl-UZ",
"uz-Latn-UZ",
"vi-VN",
"wo-SN",
"xh-ZA",
"yo-NG",
"zh-CN",
"zh-HK",
"zh-MO",
"zh-SG",
"zh-TW",
"zu-ZA"
];

var countryCode: String = "US";

for (index, languageCode) in array.enumerated() {
    let languageComponent: [String] = languageCode.components(separatedBy: "-");
    let lastElement = languageComponent[languageComponent.count - 1];
    if (lastElement == countryCode) {
        print(languageCode);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not really that correct. Try plug in country Serbia or Montenegro. It will take first from list sr-Cyrl. Hell, try plug in GB it will take cy-GB ....